# Why does Safari on mobile take so long to load images from memory?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

A strange performance issue occurs on Safari (iOS 13.5.1).

Loading images from memory takes over 300ms resulting in animation hanging (and image is not shown during animation).

When using Safari on desktop (macOS Catalina 10.15.7), load time is 3ms.

What can cause this issue?

[image: Safari]

[image: Console]

**Edit:** here are additional screenshots.

[image: Requests]

[image: Animation requests]

[image: Animation requests headers]

Comment: It looks like those PNG are coming back with a TXT mime type.  Can you look at the response headers and make sure those are correct?  Do you get a different result with `<img/>`?

Comment: Thanks for helping out @zero298. I added more screenshots... It appears the PNGs are initially served with the right MIME type. The strange `txt` MIME type is only displayed for these images loaded from memory cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Apparently Safari handles caching differently on desktop vs mobile.

My server was serving images with a no-cache polity (`Cache-Control: public, max-age=0`).

Changing policy to `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000` fixed the issue.